# Customise NSIS MessageBox title / caption

Tags: nsis

In an NSIS installer, I'm interested in displaying a MessageBox with a custom title. I currently have:

```
MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_TOPMOST "%SOME_STRING%"
```

In this call, there's no definition of MessageBox title, which then becomes a default string, saying `<Installer Name> Setup`. I would like to remove the 'Setup' part, or provide a string of my own.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Caption attribute to set the caption `Caption "Whatever"` but that changes it globally.

NSIS does not have native support for a custom MessageBox caption but you can call the Windows API directly:

```
Section
!define MB_OK 0x00000000
!define MB_ICONINFORMATION 0x00000040
System::Call 'USER32::MessageBox(i $hwndparent, t "The message", t "The caption", i ${MB_OK}|${MB_ICONINFORMATION})i'
SectionEnd
```

You can lookup the other `MB_*` flags on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx)...